React Native DevTools: How can I find a RCTView by ID or Hash
React Native tells me that my View cannot calculate a shadow efficiently.
How can I find the corresponding RCTView by ID or Hash?
I already tried searching for the Id in the search bar, but that does not work. Is there any option I can enable to show me the Id/Hash next to the View in the Components Tab?

